# how to get the date using input type date?

Tags: php, mysql

need help.. i cant get the value of input with attribute type="date".. what should i do? thanks in advance..

here is my code:

```
<form action="sales.php" method="get">
  <input type="date" name="d1" class="tcal" value="" required="required" />
  <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<?php 
  if (isset($_GET[ "d1"])) { 
    $do=$_GET[ "d1"]; 
  } else { 
    $do=0;
  }; 
  $result=$ db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date=:a");
  $result->bindParam(':a', $do); 
  $result->execute(); 
  for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){ 
?>
```

Comment: HTML 5 input types aren't supported by older web browsers, though they should behave as input type text.

Comment: im using google chrome as browser ..

Comment: `echo $_GET["d1"]` what are you getting within it

Comment: `$do=$ _GET[ "d1"];`. Check the space: it should be: `$do=$_GET[ "d1"];`

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 `<input type="date" />` will provide a string formatted this way: `YYYY-MM-DD`

So you only have to do this if you need a DateTime object for manipulation:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d|', $_GET['d1']);
```